# click function should invert color of an image and restore the color of previously inverted image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have broken an image down into parts to use for navigation.I have placed these images with z-index on each other.So the image looks like one whole image. I am using image map. I want images to invert color when mouse is hovered over them. So when mouse is on a particular area i change the z-index of that area and bring that area up and then apply color invert css to that image. When i click on an image only that part should get black and when i hover over other images the mousein mouseout options should work. When i click on another image the previous image which was clicked should become white again n this current image should remain black. Right now whats happening is previous images also remain inverted color(black) and the current image also becomes black. Here is my code for the same

```js
$(function() {
    $('area').mouseover(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('pressed')
            .css('z-index',2);
    });
});
   
function Prev()
{
$('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');

$('#'+imgid)
    .toggleClass('pressed')
    .css('z-index',2);
 
}
```

```css
#container img {position: absolute;}

img.invert {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}

img.pressed {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<body>

 <map name="map" id="id_1">
 <div="container">
<img   id="02"  src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="03"  src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="04"  src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="05"  src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="06"  src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="07"  src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="08"  src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="09"  src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10"  src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12"  src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >


</div>
   <area  data-imgid="12"  shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="11"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="10"  id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />

   <area  data-imgid="09"  class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="08"  class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="07" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   />  

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="02" id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="03" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
<div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id = "mapButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button" onclick="change_BASE_ID(curr_base_id,this.className)"><img id="image" src="prevButton.png"></button>

<button class = "nextButton" type="button" onclick="change_BASE_ID(curr_base_id,this.className)"><img id="image" src="nextButton.png"></button>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: What difference in behavoiur from what you have now do you want? (PS: It looks awesome so far!)

Comment: @Aides Thank you. I wanted two things in it. One is solved the other one is i want to two buttons down. ? One previous and the other next.  When i click on previous it should get current imgid and highlight the previous imgid and remove highlight of current imgid. When i click on next it should do the same but for next imgid. Its like a navigation coin

Comment: Okay, in that case you could take the basic idea from my answer and keep a undo/redo stack, possibly even with undo/redo functionality integrated.
This is a problem of JavaScript but a general programming pattern and you should find lots of information about it on the internet.

Comment: Also not all of your mapping seems to work correctly ;). Try hovering the **text** of "Success" or "Charakter"

Comment: @Aides I am trying everything you suggested. All your ideas seem nice to make my navigation nice.

Comment: To not further pollute the comments feel free to swing by on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/106248/discussion-between-aides-and-karen?tab=general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a line in your click function that removes the `.pressed` class from the element that you'd clicked previously

```
.click(function() {
    var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
    $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);

    $('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');

    $('#'+imgid)
        .toggleClass('pressed')
        .css('z-index',2);
});
```

Comment: Actually the other answer is correct. Just realized that calling `toggle` after `remove` will make prevent you from being able to deactivate the section when clicking on it. If that's not an intended functionality, however, then this answer works and it makes sense to change the `toggle` call to `add` instead

Comment: How do i work this functionality also with the button? I want to navigate the coin on button previous and next along with click.

Answer (score 4):

remove the `pressed` class from the other elements within the click handler

```
.click(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);
        var $currImg =  $('#'+imgid)
        $('.pressed').not($currImg).removeClass('pressed');
        $currImg
            .toggleClass('pressed')
            .css('z-index',2);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For only having one selected item I would just store the selected item in a variable and toggle it back on the next selection (also consider creating functions for selecting/unselecting).

```js
$(function() {
    var selectedItem;

    $('area').mouseover(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {

        if(selectedItem)
        {
            selectedItem
                .toggleClass('pressed')
                .css('z-index', 1);
            selectedItem = null;
        }

        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('pressed')
            .css('z-index',2);

        selectedItem = $('#'+imgid);
    });
});
```